# React testing library event not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test user events on my react code using react-testing library. However, neither the "uservent" nor "fireEvent" is updating the state.

```
const dropdown = screen.getByRole('combobox', {
  name: /Use DNS Server for/i
});
expect(dropdown).toHaveValue('auto');
await userEvent.selectOptions(dropdown, 'globalDNS');
await waitFor(() => expect(dropdown).toHaveValue('globalDNS'));
```

This is the code i am trying to test.

`<select id="dnsMode_GuiHelper2" class="form-select"><option value="auto">Search Domains (if available)</option><option value="globalDNS">All Domains</option></select>`

The first expect passes but the fails on the second one, saying the value is still "auto".

```
Expected the element to have value:
  globalDNS
Received:
  auto
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.
P.S: I have checked using console.log that getByRole is returning the HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fireEvent.change` like in this example:

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';


test('Simulates selection', () => {
  const { getByTestId, getAllByTestId } = render(<App />);
  //The value should be the key of the option
  fireEvent.change(getByTestId('select'), { target: { value: 2 } })
  let options = getAllByTestId('select-option')
  expect(options[0].selected).toBeFalsy();
  expect(options[1].selected).toBeTruthy();
  expect(options[2].selected).toBeFalsy();
  //...
})
```